# Assign decimal to object property xaml

Tags: .net, xaml

If i have a property of type object in the DataContext.

How can i assign a decimal value to this property through xaml?

If i try

```
<test:Test Prop="2" />
```

this will assign a string value, not a decimal value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself.

```
<test:Test>
    <test:Test.Property>
        <System:Decimal>5</System:Decimal>
    </test:Test.Property>
</test:Test>
```

Answer (score 0):

if your property Test.Prop is of type decimal, then it will automatically convert it to a decimal using the built in type converters.